# How do I create a refresh button in Openedge?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

On a screen I need to create a refresh button, the button I created, but I want to know how I can incorporate the refresh functionality.

Comment: What kind of GUI are you trying to refresh? Dotnet, web, old style graphical client, smart window etc?

Comment: @Jensd It is in openedge frame. Where I used the Browse:REFRESH() function. In this way I could incorporate the REFRESH functionality.

Answer (score 3):

1) Using the Appbuilder palette select the button widget.

2) Place it on your openedge frame.  It doesn't have to be a smart frame.

3) Go to the trigger section of that button. The editor should open up with the "On Choose" trigger automatically selected.

4) Add code in the choose trigger to call the refresh method of the browse.

Here's a code snippet to get you going:

On "Choose" of "Button-1" in frame fMain
   DO:

```
  browse BROWSE-1:refresh().

 {&OPEN-QUERY-{&BROWSE-NAME}}
```

END.

Notes:

1) the On Choose part should be written for you by the appbuilder.

2) Replace BROWSE-1 with the widget name of your browse widget.

3) The refresh method on the browse may not reread data from the database.  You'll need to reopen the query to fetch the latest records.

Hope this helps.